# add an airflow connection to a localhost database (postgres running on docker)

Tags: postgresql, docker, airflow

I have a dockerized postgres running locally, to which I can connect to via pgAdmin4 and via `psql`.

Using the same connection details, I set up an airflow connection on the UI

[image]

However, when trying to load a DAG that uses that connection, it throws an error:

> Broken DAG: [/usr/local/airflow/dags/s3upload.py] Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/providers/postgres/hooks/postgres.py", line 113, in get_conn
> self.conn = psycopg2.connect(**conn_args)
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/**init**.py", line 127, in connect
> conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
> psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
> Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
> TCP/IP connections on port 54320?

As mentioned, the postgres instance is running, and the port forwarding is active, as proven by successful pgAdmin and `psql` logins.

Any ideas?

Comment: is the airflow running in another docker container ?

Comment: it is! didn't think of that... would you know how to correctly define the host in that case?

Comment: yes, just answered

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use `host.docker.internal`, which will point to your localhost and not the container localhost, it will work if the pg port is mapped to your 5432 port.

Comment: alternatively you can also enter 'postgres' as the host